# Using a runtime string to specify object type in natvis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, natvis

Say I have a struct

```
struct Foo
{
    void* bar;
    const char* barTypeName;
}
```

`bar` is some type erased thing and `barTypeName` is a proper C++ type identifier that identifies the actual type of `bar`.

I want to visualize this in the Visual Studio debugger, particularly in the Watch window. There's no template involved that can give me the proper type. The type itself is frequently POD and the debugger isn't able to figure out the type automatically.

**Question:** Is there any way in natvis to tell the debugger the type of `bar` so it displays properly in the Watch window?

I stumbled on `<MostDerivedType>` in the [natvis schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis), but it's not [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects) as far as I can tell and I can't tell if it does what I'm after or not.

I'm happy enough to use `<CustomVisualizer>` and implement this in C++ if it provides a way to handle this and natvis does not.

Comment: You can use a cast in the watch window. As you have erased the type the debugger needs some help.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite simple if you are willing to add a `DisplayString` for each wrapped POD. If you want a generic solution, that might not be possible.

```
<Type Name="Foo">
  <DisplayString Condition='strcmp(barTypeName,"char")'>{(char)bar}</DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition='strcmp(barTypeName,"int")'>{(int)bar}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Code for testing:

```
char c{};
int i{};
Foo fooc{ &c, "char" };
Foo fooi{ &i, "int" };
```

And this is the result in the VS 2019 (16.11.11) debugger:

[image]